# edit a range of elements inside a 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

well ive been trying to edit the element of an array so lets assume that we have a 2d array

so
   a 2d array 9 x 9;

```
     for(... ... ... ++)
         {
            for(.. ... ...++){}
         }
```

lets say that the code will use another set of for loops to display the 2d array its a simple array nothing fancy

```
                                00000000
                                00000000
                                00000000...
```

so if i wanted to to display an E from elements[1][0] to [2][3] how would i do that?

```
              00000000
              eeeeeeee
              eeee0000
              00000000
```

what i had in mind was something like while(x < y)
{ array[x++][y];}
but this idea doesnt seem to work. 
would gladly take any help. thx

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        board[i][j] = grid; // set the array to the char on grid '0'.
    }
}
board[s_col][s_row] = 'Z';
while(s_col < e_col)//s_col is the start of the rows and columns
    //{
    //if(s_col != e_col)
{
    ++s_col;
    board[s_col][s_row];
}
//}
//cout << board[s_col][s_row++] <<endl;

// display the array
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cout << board[i][j]  << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: For starters, you might want to make your code more concrete! The one thing I can already comment on, though, is that C++ prefers preincrement over postincrement, despite its name (although, it won't matter for your problem).

Comment: thx kuhl. i had ++s_col; tho i didnt use it ;p. as for more code im kinda of new here so using 8 spaces between each line was painful. if there is an easy way to it i dont know it yet

Comment: You merely need to start each line of code with 4 spaces followed by normal indentation (I don't know what tabs do but you shouldn't use tabs anyway). Any half-way decent editor lets you insert 4 spaces in front of each line, e.g., I'm using `:%s/^/    /` from `vi`.

Comment: thx again kuhl. tried to put more stuff now, i have to go study but i will try my best to keep the question/myself updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the approach:

```
 for(... ... ... ++)
    {
       for(.. ... ...++){}
    }
```

Here is some code that should help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define MAX_ROW 4
#define MAX_COL 8

void fillRange(char fillChar, int startRow, int startCol, int count);

char myArray[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
void printArray();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  memset(myArray, '0', sizeof(myArray));

  printf("\nBefore:\n");
  printArray();
  fillRange('e', 1, 0, 12);
  printf("\nAfter:\n");
  printArray();

}

void fillRange(char fillChar, int startRow, int startCol, int count)
{
  int i, j, filledChars = 0;

  for(i = startRow; i < MAX_ROW; i++)
  {
    for(j = startCol; j < MAX_COL; j++)
    {
      myArray[i][j] = fillChar;
      if(++filledChars == count)
        return;
    }
  }
}

void printArray()
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROW; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_COL; j++)
      putchar(myArray[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

If you instead wanted to end at a particular point in the array then you just need to change the condition that triggers the return.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons why the more coding you do the more you tend to avoid 2D arrays of the sort you have.

Instead you use a 1D array like this: `board[i][j] == board_1D[i*num_columns+j]`. That also means you can just iterate through the entire board in a single `for` loop.

Now you simply calculate the begin and end indices of your `e` range, and simply test if your counter is within that range. In other words, you have a single `if` statement inside your inner-most loop.

You can, of course, convert your `i`,`j` 2D indices into the equivalent 1D index and take the same approach. `index_1D = i*9+j;`

I'll leave the code to you.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with a sequence of adjacent values is easiest done when you have an underlying contiguous array and you don't need to deal with double indexing (see Adam's answer on that). However, in your simple case it also quite doable:

You'd initialize your `row` and `column` variables with the start row and column (in your case `0` and `1`). You then walk with your `column` until you reached either the target column (2) *and* you are on the target row (3) or you reached the end of the matrix in which case you set the column to `0` and increment the `row`.